# No variables seen in the debugging window in Vimspector while debugging a c++ program in Neovim. Breakpoints set are not seen too

Tags: c++, ubuntu, debugging, neovim, vimspector

I am new to this Neovim debugging using Vimspector. When i set breakpoints and open debugger i am unable to see any variables or see breakpoints itself. What might be wrong here?
[Vimspector Debugger when opened,showing no variables or break points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftDB4.png)

[Code with breakpoint set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqoYU.png)

Below is my .vimspector.json

```
{
"configurations": {
  "C - Launch": {
    "adapter": "vscode-cpptools",
    "configuration": {
      "request": "launch",
      "externalConsole": true,
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/test"
    }
  }
  }
}
```

---

Below is my innit.vim code if needed:

```
:set number
:set relativenumber
:set autoindent
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set smarttab
:set softtabstop=4
:set mouse=a

call plug#begin()
Plug 'voldikss/vim-browser-search'
   Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
    Plug 'pineapplegiant/spaceduck', { 'branch': 'main' }
Plug 'https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal'
Plug 'http://github.com/tpope/vim-surround' " Surrounding ysw)
Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary' " For Commenting gcc & gc
Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline' " Status bar
Plug 'https://github.com/lifepillar/pgsql.vim' 
Plug 'https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color' " CSS Color Preview
Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes' " Retro Scheme
Plug 'https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim'  " Auto Completion
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/tagbar' " Tagbar for code navigation
Plug 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " CTRL + N for multiple cursors
Plug 'https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector'
set encoding=UTF-8
call plug#end()

let g:vimspector_enable_mappings = 'HUMAN'



nmap <silent> <Leader>s <Plug>SearchNormal
vmap <silent> <Leader>s <Plug>SearchVisual
nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <C-l> :call CocActionAsync('jumpDefinition')<CR>

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

:set completeopt-=preview " For No Previews

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"

" --- Just Some Notes ---
" :PlugClean :PlugInstall :UpdateRemotePlugins
"
" :CocInstall coc-python
" :CocInstall coc-clangd
" :CocInstall coc-snippets
" :CocCommand snippets.edit... FOR EACH FILE TYPE

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "<Tab>"


  if exists('+termguicolors')
      let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
      let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
      set termguicolors
    endif

   colorscheme spaceduck

let g:vimspector_enable_mappings = 'HUMAN'
nnoremap <Leader>dd :call vimspector#Launch()<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>dx :call vimspector#Reset()<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>de :call vimspectorEval
nnoremap <Leader>dw :call vimspectorWatch
nnoremap <Leader>do :call vimspectorShowOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is same with me, solution is:
Compile source code with option -g to generate debug info, eg. `gcc -g -o test test.c` .

after that Vimspector vairable diplay correctly.

You should try gdb first, eg. `gdb test`, gcc without option -g, output:

> Reading symbols from test... (No debugging symbols found in test)